# how to retrieve mobilenumber from Mysql using Json in Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am Using `JSON` to retrieve details(fname,email,bikeno,mobileno) from MySQL database when user login. All details are retreiving except mobile number.

[image: My DateBase Table]

[image: Thats the phone number]

My Code is :

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
progressBar.setCancelable(true);
progressBar.setMessage("Logging You in");
progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressBar.show();
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject jsonObject1= jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String code = jsonObject.getString("code");

                if (code.equals("login_failed")) {

                    builder.setTitle("Login Error");
                    displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("email1", jsonObject.getString("email"));
                    bundle.putString("bikeno1", jsonObject.getString("bikeno"));
                    bundle.putString("fname", jsonObject.getString("fname"));
                    bundle.putString("mobileno", jsonObject.getString("mobileno"));
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My Question is how to get mobile number and how to send that value to another activity?

Comment: are u getting mobile no in your json response.

Comment: No bro. It showing Logging You in but its not logging when i comment this line "bundle.putString("mobileno", jsonObject.getString("mobileno"));" then its able to login in app

Comment: Show the `JSON` in `response`.

Comment: paste your json response.

Comment: share your php and json response.. may be you are not getting any mobile number in json response

Comment: @Androidjack bro you are right problem in json response i got it Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:
php:

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";

require_once('connectionphp.php');

$r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$result1 = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
array_push($result1,array(
    'mobilenum'=>$row['mobilenum']
));
}

echo json_encode($result1);
```

and try to retrive it in your java like this:

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String , String>();
            params.put(KEY_MOBILE, mobilenum);


            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

and get the bundle like this in next Activity:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        mob= extras.getString("mobileno");
    }
```